# Don't understand the use of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in the following proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a short vacation from school which I'm using to try to understand this semester's material. I've stumbled upon this short proof, and I don't understand how the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is used in it:

[image]

Does anyone understand? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality states that $|\left<x,y\right>| \leq ||x|| \cdot ||y||$ where $x,y$ are vectors in an inner product space. 
It can also be stated as: 
$$|\sum_i x_i y_i| \leq \sqrt {\sum_i |x_i|^2} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_j |y_j|^2}$$
Where $x_i,y_i \in \mathbb R$ for every $i$ (i.e substituting vectors in $R^n$).

In your case:
$$\sum_b {||u_b| - |v_b|| (|u_b + |v_b|)} = \sum_b {||u_b| - |v_b|| \cdot |u_b|} + \sum_b{||u_b| - |v_b|| \cdot |v_b|}$$
So we can use the inequality twice, taking $x_b = ||u_b| - |v_b||$ and $y_{b_1} = |u_b|$ , $y_{b_2} = |v_b|$